# Router F680 WLAN and LAN isolation

Tags: networking, lan

The computers connected to the WLAN network doesn't communicate with the LAN network (the computers that are directly connected to the router, by ethernet cable)

I tried all the options and trying to reset the router several times, but the problem still there. What can I do? I unchecked all the SSID isolation and Wireless isolation but still doesn't work. Any ideas?

[image: Address Table Of Router]

[image: Ping doesn't work with LAN but SSID1]

Answer (score 0):

On my F670, I had to take attention to these two points :

- "Network / WLAN Radio2.4G / Basic / Enable Isolation" unticked (also for "WLAN Radio5G") ;
- "Network / LAN / DHCP Port Service / Dhcp Mode": Lan for the SSID you use.

I do not use the default LAN configuration (not 192.168.1.0/24), and without the DHCP mode to LAN, I did not have access to Internet from my wireless devices.
With DHCP mode to LAN, I get access to Internet AND I am able to ping between wired and wireless devices.