# Router ZTE F680 - my PCs cannot see each other

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I have a ZTE F680 (internet router) from our ISP

if I connect the PC to the LAN1 or any (2,3,4) I can not see other PCs which are connected to the router.

If I connect on the same WiFi SSID they can ping or see each others shared files.

When I connect my PCs to AP all of them can see each other as well.

Comment: Check network discovery again and make sure devices you wish to see are all on one subnet.

Comment: Hi all on same subnet

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your answer is here:
[Router F680 WLAN and LAN isolation](https://superuser.com/questions/1287532/router-f680-wlan-and-lan-isolation)

You need to disable the LAN isolation.